# Moving to Extension Library

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Am I able to include the screens into Extension Library ? DACs can be converted into Extensions and be added to the library. But not sure about the screens though.

Comment: Hi, was my answer of any help? did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Well, not really. I thought I can wrap all customisations into a single DLL. These include the scripts, ASPX etc. We have some IP sensitive work rolled out to a number of clients. And hiding them too peering eyes is one thing. But thanks for the input.

Comment: OK, just keep in mind that even if you move to a DLL, your code can easily be decompiled (unless you somehow manage to obfuscate it).

Comment: Unless obfuscating the dll can be decompiled easily as Joseph mentioned. All files exist on their own in the customization. So the dll and pages are separate files and would exist as such.

Comment: I agree. But we've already covered the obfuscation part. The way I see it is to separate the projects between one offs and not. The one off projects can be unpublished and deleted once it's done its job. And I suppose its not the end of the world if we can leave the ASPX exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Your screens should remain in the customization project. You can however edited them from Visual Studio, but remmember to go back to Customizations Project Files |  Files and click Detected Modified Files so that the file is updated in the Customization Project. You then typically use the 'Save to Folder' function so that your Customization Project can be added to Source Control.